# How send lists of objects with GAE endpoints?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm working in a API in GAE and I'm using Endpoints (with python). The data that I want send with response are a few objects that I build in this moment. So, to send this objects, I build a class with ProtoRPC message. And how I want send a list of them I build a class that represent a collections or a list of them.

This is the basis code:

```
class Greeting(messages.Message):
"""Greeting that stores a message."""
message = messages.StringField(1)

class GreetingCollection(messages.Message):
    """Collection of Greetings."""
    items = messages.MessageField(Greeting, 1, repeated=True)
```

But when I want build a collection, I don't found the way. Obviously, seeing the documentation, I read that I can build a static colection to send it, for example:

```
STORED_GREETINGS = GreetingCollection(items=[
    Greeting(message='hello world!'),
    Greeting(message='goodbye world!'),
])
```

But if I want build this dynamically?
In my case I have a process that return a list of Greetings, and I dont find the way to convert this to a collection of Greeting to send with EndPoints.

```
return STORED_GREETINGS
```

Maybe I'm searching **something like this**:

```
(only orientative)
for greeting in greetings:
   STORED_GREETINGS.add(greeting)
```

but I don't find how doing.

Any help will be welcome. 
Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a normal list containing the Greeting objects and assign it to the GreetingCollection:

```
    greetingItems = []
    greetingItems.append(Greeting(message='hello world!'))
    greetingItems.append(Greeting(message='goodbye world!'))
    ...

    STORED_GREETINGS = GreetingCollection(items=greetingItems)
```

Comment: It's perfect @ChrisC73 ! I don't know how I don't thought this before! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just do:

```
greeting_collection = GreetingCollection()
greeting_collection.items = list_of_greetings
```

Or, alternatively:

```
greeting_collection = GreetingCollection()
greeting_collection.items.extend(iterable_of_greetings)
```

Comment: I don't can do this directly because both objects are not the same kind.

```AttributeError: May not assign arbitrary value py/object to message Greeting```